# Sort Struct in ColdFusion on Values ASC

Tags: sorting, coldfusion

How can I sort this structure by the values in ASC order?

```
<cfset dStruct = createObject("java", "java.util.LinkedHashMap").init()>
<cfquery name="gds" datasource="#application.dsn#">
    SELECT * FROM stores WHERE region_id = #arguments.retailer_id# 
    ORDER BY client_loc ASC
</cfquery>

<cfoutput query="gds">
    <cfset var dStru = { "#gds.storeid#" = "#gds.client_loc# - #gds.city#, #gds.state#" }>
    <cfset StructAppend( dStruct, dStru )>
</cfoutput>

<cfset StructSort(dStruct,"textnocase","asc")>
....
<cfreturn SerializeJSON(dStruct) />
```

The results then populate a  drop down. Here are the results:

```
struct
299 | ASH041 - ONTARIO, CA
300 | ASH042 - CLEARWATER, FL
301 | ASH044 - TAMPA, FL
302 | ASH046 - ORLANDO, FL
303 | ASH047 - SARASOTA, FL
304 | ASH048 - TAMPA, FL
305 | ASH002 - HUNTINGTON STN., NY
```

If it was sorting correctly, ASH002 would be the first result, but it appears to be sorting on the KEY instead of the VALUE. Is there a way to sort by the values?

I also tried this...

```
<cfset dStruct = createObject("java", "java.util.LinkedHashMap").init() />
```

Either way produces the same results. Here is a screenshot of the results...

[image: screenshot]

Here is the jquery that populates the select menu.

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "/functions.cfc",
            cache: false, 
            type: "get",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {method: "getstoresbyretailer", retailer_id: (retailer_id)}, //get stores
            success: function (data) { 

                var $select = $('#storeid'); 
                $select.find('option').remove();

                $.each(data,function(key, value) {
                    $select.append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value + '</option>');
                });

            }
        });
```

Comment: A LinkedHashMap will maintain the insertion order. However, that means you must ORDER the query results by the "title" value, *not* storeid.

Comment: You are correct, that was a typo. I am sorting by client_loc, but it's still not being returned to the calling page in the correct sort order.

Answer (score 4):

Ordering within your SQL statement would be the best solution here:

`ORDER BY storeid, client_loc, city, state`

and then loop over your query and generate the options.

---

But to answer your question:

If you want to sort an unlinked struct (`dStruct`) and keep an ordered struct, you have to use a linked struct (`LinkedHashMap`):

```
<cfset sortedKeys   = structSort(dStruct, "textnocase", "asc")>
<cfset sortedStruct = createObject("java", "java.util.LinkedHashMap").init()>

<cfloop array="#sortedKeys#" index="key">
    <cfset sortedStruct[key] = dStruct[key]>
</cfloop>

<cfoutput>

    <select>
        <cfloop collection="#sortedStruct#" item="key">
            <option>#encodeForHtml(sortedStruct[key])#</option>
        </cfloop>
    </select>

</cfoutput>
```

Note that using `cfdump` does not display the real order of a linked struct.

Comment: *cfdump does not display the real order of a linked struct* Yep. It usually displays things in what it considers the most user friendly manner. With structures, that means alphabetically.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. That seems to work if I run it on a test page - but in production, I am calling the component with jquery/ajax and returning the values which populate the select.

Comment: Hang on, I made some progress using HashMap. The json returned is in the correct order, BUT the select menu is still whacked. What is causing that? {"305":"ASH002 - HUNTINGTON STN., NY","310":"ASH003 - CARLE PLACE, NY","318":"ASH004 - FOREST HILLS, NY","322":"ASH005 - BROOKLYN, NY","323":"ASH006 - WHITE PLAINS, NY","324":"ASH007 - NEW YORK, NY"}

Comment: @Bobmd - Thanks for posting your solution. Generally, structures have no guaranteed order. So even if the LinkedHashMap maintains the insertion order, it is possible the next step in the chain, ie jQuery will not preserve that order after deserialization.  Since the order is significant, using an array was probably the better choice.

Comment: @Leigh & Alex I was really stuck and couldn't have done it without you. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

thanks so much for your help. I figured out a solution... by returning an array of objects.

```
function getstoresbyretailer(retailer_id) { 

$.ajax({
    url: "/functions.cfc",
    cache: false, 
    type: "get",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {method: "getstoresbyretailer", retailer_id: (retailer_id)}, 
    success: function (data) { 

        var $select = $('#storeid'); 
        $select.find('option').remove();

        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            $select.append('<option value=' + value.storeid + '>' + value.store + '</option>');
        });
    }
}); 
}
```

And the ColdFusion Function...

```
<cffunction name="getstoresbyretailer" access="remote" returnformat="json" output="no">
    <cfargument name="retailer_id" type="numeric" required="yes">

    <cfset var dArray = []>
    <cfif arguments.retailer_id neq 0>

        <cfquery name="gds" datasource="#application.dsn#">
            SELECT * FROM stores WHERE region_id = #arguments.retailer_id# 
            ORDER BY client_loc ASC
        </cfquery>

        <cfif gds.recordcount>

            <cfoutput query="gds">
                <cfset dStru = { "storeid" = "#gds.storeid#", "store" = "#gds.client_loc# - #gds.city#, #gds.state#" }>
                <cfset ArrayAppend( dArray, dStru )>
            </cfoutput>

        </cfif>

    </cfif>

    <cfreturn SerializeJSON(dArray) />
</cffunction>
```

Figured someone might be able to use this one day.